# How to add Msctf.dll as reference path to c# project?

Tags: c#, com

I need to write a COM object in c# inorder to utilize i need to add Msctf.dll as reference to C# project .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on Add Reference of your project and browse to your path of  Msctf.dll

link (Register COM) : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859484.aspx

Comment: i am getting an error saying "please make sure that is valid library or COM"

Comment: you must register your com : regsvr32